# Don't read next Kafka message until current message is processed?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

When consuming messages using the Confluent Kafka C# library, I only want to see a new message when I've finished processing the current one (I need to read the same message again if something fails). In other words, I don't want the offset to change until I explicitly tell it to change.

To try achieve this, I deactivate auto-commiting in the config (just like in the examples):

```
{ "enable.auto.commit", false }
{ "auto.offset.reset", "smallest" }
```

I then comment out the commit line:

```
while(true)
{
    if (!consumer.Consume(out Message<string, string> msg, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)))
    {
        continue;
    }

    //I thought by removing this line, I would keep getting the same message (until I've processed the message and commited the offset)
    //consumer.CommitAsync(msg).Result;
}
```

My hope was that by not commiting, I would keep getting the same message when calling Consume(), but this isn't the case. Even though I don't commit, the offset keeps changing and I keep getting new messages every consumption.

Please clear up my obvious misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `CommitAsync` saves your offset to an offset topic stored by kafka. So if you were to dispose your Consumer and create a new one you would start again from the last committed offset, or if you don't commit the offset you would start from offset 0.

If don't commit the offset but continue using the same consumer in your app then the offset will still be incremented and held in-memory by the consumer.

Although this is documentation for the Java consumer class under the section **Offsets and Consumer Position** it states in more detail the function of offsets and committing. [KafkaConsumer Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

Comment: That makes sense thank you, how would this be approached then? Does the consumer have any setting to tell it not to alter the offset in memory unless told to? Or what is the appropriate approach to take when you can't process the next message until the current is finished.

Comment: In your current example as your calling Consume in a while loop as long as what your processing doesn't take place in an different thread and not waited for completion. It should wait for the code to execute before consuming the next message.

Comment: Also if you need to reprocess the existing message due to an error you could do something like: `consumer.Seek(msg.TopicPartitionOffset);` That will set the consumers offset back to the offset of the currently processed message.